# Is the Google maps api suitable for non-geographical views?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I am making an Android app which requires a main view with similar functionality to the Google maps app; i.e. zooming, panning and rotating through a view made up programatically.

There will be no actual maps, the data will be built up based on user actions. Is a mapview the way to approach this, or is the class tied in to using actual locations? If it's not the right thing to be looking at, what should I be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView seems to be more appropriate. WebView supports zooming and panning and you can build your data representation with standard HTML and CSS.